# Rack mini profiler error in heroku even when gem is removed in gemfile

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, heroku, rack-mini-profiler

I'm getting this error when I push to heroku master:

```
remote: -----> Installing node-v12.16.2-linux-x64
remote: -----> Installing yarn-v1.22.4
remote: -----> Detecting rake tasks
remote: -----> Preparing app for Rails asset pipeline
remote:        Running: rake assets:precompile
remote:        rake aborted!
remote:        NameError: uninitialized constant Rack::MiniProfiler
remote:        Did you mean?  MiniMime
remote:        /tmp/build_416cf9b1/config/initializers/rack_mini_profiler.rb:1:in `<main>'
remote:        /tmp/build_416cf9b1/vendor/bundle/ruby/3.0.0/gems/bootsnap-1.7.5/lib/bootsnap/load_path_cache/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:59:in `load'
remote:        /tmp/build_416cf9b1/vendor/bundle/ruby/3.0.0/gems/bootsnap-1.7.5/lib/bootsnap/load_path_cache/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:59:in `load'
remote:        /tmp/build_416cf9b1/vendor/bundle/ruby/3.0.0/gems/railties-6.1.4/lib/rails/engine.rb:681:in `block in load_config_initializer'
remote:        /tmp/build_416cf9b1/vendor/bundle/ruby/3.0.0/gems/activesupport-6.1.4/lib/active_support/notifications.rb:205:in `instrument'
remote:        /tmp/build_416cf9b1/vendor/bundle/ruby/3.0.0/gems/railties-6.1.4/lib/rails/engine.rb:680:in `load_config_initializer'
remote:        /tmp/build_416cf9b1/vendor/bundle/ruby/3.0.0/gems/railties-6.1.4/lib/rails/engine.rb:634:in `block (2 levels) in <class:Engine>'
remote:        /tmp/build_416cf9b1/vendor/bundle/ruby/3.0.0/gems/railties-6.1.4/lib/rails/engine.rb:633:in `each'
remote:        /tmp/build_416cf9b1/vendor/bundle/ruby/3.0.0/gems/railties-6.1.4/lib/rails/engine.rb:633:in `block in <class:Engine>'
remote:        /tmp/build_416cf9b1/vendor/bundle/ruby/3.0.0/gems/railties-6.1.4/lib/rails/initializable.rb:32:in `instance_exec'
remote:        /tmp/build_416cf9b1/vendor/bundle/ruby/3.0.0/gems/railties-6.1.4/lib/rails/initializable.rb:32:in `run'
remote:        /tmp/build_416cf9b1/vendor/bundle/ruby/3.0.0/gems/railties-6.1.4/lib/rails/initializable.rb:61:in `block in run_initializers'
remote:        /tmp/build_416cf9b1/vendor/bundle/ruby/3.0.0/gems/railties-6.1.4/lib/rails/initializable.rb:50:in `each'
remote:        /tmp/build_416cf9b1/vendor/bundle/ruby/3.0.0/gems/railties-6.1.4/lib/rails/initializable.rb:50:in `tsort_each_child'
remote:        /tmp/build_416cf9b1/vendor/bundle/ruby/3.0.0/gems/railties-6.1.4/lib/rails/initializable.rb:60:in `run_initializers'
remote:        /tmp/build_416cf9b1/vendor/bundle/ruby/3.0.0/gems/railties-6.1.4/lib/rails/application.rb:391:in `initialize!'
remote:        /tmp/build_416cf9b1/config/environment.rb:5:in `<main>'
remote:        /tmp/build_416cf9b1/vendor/bundle/ruby/3.0.0/gems/bootsnap-1.7.5/lib/bootsnap/load_path_cache/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:23:in `require'
remote:        /tmp/build_416cf9b1/vendor/bundle/ruby/3.0.0/gems/bootsnap-1.7.5/lib/bootsnap/load_path_cache/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:23:in `block in require_with_bootsnap_lfi'
remote:        /tmp/build_416cf9b1/vendor/bundle/ruby/3.0.0/gems/bootsnap-1.7.5/lib/bootsnap/load_path_cache/loaded_features_index.rb:92:in `register'
remote:        /tmp/build_416cf9b1/vendor/bundle/ruby/3.0.0/gems/bootsnap-1.7.5/lib/bootsnap/load_path_cache/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:22:in `require_with_bootsnap_lfi'
remote:        /tmp/build_416cf9b1/vendor/bundle/ruby/3.0.0/gems/bootsnap-1.7.5/lib/bootsnap/load_path_cache/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:31:in `require'
remote:        /tmp/build_416cf9b1/vendor/bundle/ruby/3.0.0/gems/zeitwerk-2.4.2/lib/zeitwerk/kernel.rb:34:in `require'
remote:        /tmp/build_416cf9b1/vendor/bundle/ruby/3.0.0/gems/railties-6.1.4/lib/rails/application.rb:367:in `require_environment!'
remote:        /tmp/build_416cf9b1/vendor/bundle/ruby/3.0.0/gems/railties-6.1.4/lib/rails/application.rb:533:in `block in run_tasks_blocks'
remote:        /tmp/build_416cf9b1/vendor/bundle/ruby/3.0.0/gems/sprockets-rails-3.2.2/lib/sprockets/rails/task.rb:61:in `block (2 levels) in define'
remote:        Tasks: TOP => environment
remote:        (See full trace by running task with --trace)
remote:
remote:  !
remote:  !     Precompiling assets failed.
remote:  !
remote:  !     Push rejected, failed to compile Ruby app.
remote:
remote:  !     Push failed
remote:  !
remote:  ! ## Warning - The same version of this code has already been built: 7a96920071719fb5e5e9f1de7ca2a992afdd3266
remote:  !
remote:  ! We have detected that you have triggered a build from source code with version 7a96920071719fb5e5e9f1de7ca2a992afdd3266
remote:  ! at least twice. One common cause of this behavior is attempting to deploy code from a different branch.
remote:  !
remote:  ! If you are developing on a branch and deploying via git you must run:
remote:  !
remote:  !     git push heroku <branchname>:main
remote:  !
remote:  ! This article goes into details on the behavior:
remote:  !   https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/duplicate-build-version
remote:
remote: Verifying deploy...
remote:
remote: !       Push rejected to spaces-todoapp-ror.
remote:
To https://git.heroku.com/spaces-todoapp-ror.git
 ! [remote rejected] master -> master (pre-receive hook declined)
error: failed to push some refs to 'https://git.heroku.com/spaces-todoapp-ror.git'
```

Here's my current Gemfile:

```
# frozen_string_literal: true

source 'https://rubygems.org'
git_source(:github) { |repo| "https://github.com/#{repo}.git" }

ruby '3.0.1'

# Bundle edge Rails instead: gem 'rails', github: 'rails/rails', branch: 'main'
gem 'rails', '~> 6.1.4'
# Use postgresql as the database for Active Record
gem 'pg', '~> 1.1'
# Use Puma as the app server
gem 'puma', '~> 5.0'
# Use SCSS for stylesheets
gem 'sass-rails', '>= 6'
# Transpile app-like JavaScript. Read more: https://github.com/rails/webpacker
gem 'webpacker', '~> 5.0'
# Turbolinks makes navigating your web application faster. Read more: https://github.com/turbolinks/turbolinks
gem 'turbolinks', '~> 5'
# Build JSON APIs with ease. Read more: https://github.com/rails/jbuilder
gem 'jbuilder', '~> 2.7'
# Use Redis adapter to run Action Cable in production
# gem 'redis', '~> 4.0'
# Use Active Model has_secure_password
# gem 'bcrypt', '~> 3.1.7'

# Use Active Storage variant
# gem 'image_processing', '~> 1.2'

# Reduces boot times through caching; required in config/boot.rb
gem 'bootsnap', '>= 1.4.4', require: false
gem 'devise'

group :development, :test do
  # Call 'byebug' anywhere in the code to stop execution and get a debugger console
  gem 'byebug', platforms: %i[mri mingw x64_mingw]
end

group :development do
  # Access an interactive console on exception pages or by calling 'console' anywhere in the code.
  gem 'web-console', '>= 4.1.0'
  # Display performance information such as SQL time and flame graphs for each request in your browser.
  gem 'listen', '~> 3.3'
  # Spring speeds up development by keeping your application running in the background. Read more: https://github.com/rails/spring
  gem 'spring'
end

group :test do
  # Adds support for Capybara system testing and selenium driver
  gem 'capybara', '>= 3.26'
  gem 'selenium-webdriver'
  # Easy installation and use of web drivers to run system tests with browsers
  gem 'webdrivers'
end

# Windows does not include zoneinfo files, so bundle the tzinfo-data gem
gem 'tzinfo-data', platforms: %i[mingw mswin x64_mingw jruby]
```

During the early stages of development, I installed the rack-mini-profiler gem to move the annoying timer in new rails apps to the bottom. Then when I tried pushing to heroku, I encountered this error. I then removed the gem in my Gemfile, ran bundle install, and also removed the rack mini profiler file in config/initializers. Still got the same error. I tried deleting the app in heroku and started a new one and when I pushed, I got the same error. Now I even deleted the actual gem but still, same error. I even scanned the rails files and looked for the keyword 'rack' but I found nothing. I don't know why it's still giving me an uninitialized constant when I can't find any trace of it now in my app. Thanks in advance for helping!

Answer (score 1):

I fixed it.
I thought at first just making new pushes to heroku remote will 'refresh' it and forget about trying to find the rack mini profiler so I made trivial changes like deleting some comments--it didn't work. I then pushed those changes to github instead. Pulled those changes to local then tried pushing to heroku again and that's it. No idea why it worked ‍♂️